# sql query question inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
LEFT JOIN PatientClinics AB ON PPhy.PatientID = AB.PatientID 
     JOIN Clinics CL ON CL.ID = AB.ClinicID 
                    AND COUNT(AB.ClinicID) = 1
```

I get error using `Count(AB.ClinicID) = 1`   (ClinicID has duplicate values in the table and
I want to use only 1 value of each duplicate value of ClinicId to produce result)

What mistake am I making?

Comment: Can you post the entire query, otherwise its hard to help..

Comment: I agree -- need more SQL to get a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Count()` can't be used as a join/filter predicate.  It can be used in the `HAVING` clause however.  You should include the entire query in order to get a better example of how to rewrite it.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen a `COUNT()` being used in a `JOIN` before.  Maybe you should use:

`HAVING COUNT(AB.ClinicID) = 1`

instead.

Comment: Wouldn't this restrict the output to only clinics with no duplicate entries?

Comment: @StevieG: Quote the OP: "ClinicID has *duplicate values* in the table and I want to use only 1 value of each duplicate value of ClinicId to produce result"

Comment: @OMG Ponies: My thinking was that PatientClinics is a junction table, and he probably wants to join on the first ClinicId for a given patient, as opposed to only including patients with only only 1 entry in the junction table. Either way, we can't really give a definitive answer without seeing the entire SQL..

Answer (score 0):

maybe investigate the `HAVING` clause instead of using `COUNT` where you put it.

hard to help without the full query.